# How to use Apostrophe in <xsl:apply-templates> select

Tags: xslt, escaping

i have to add Apostrophe(') in select attribute of  tag .

Like this

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Object[@class='name of' class']" mode="name of' class" />
```

There is Apostrophe(') in class name . Here in between name of and class .

Answer (score 2):

In XSLT 2.0, you can double the delimiter used for a string literal:

```
select="Object[@class='name of'' class']"
```

If you want to escape the delimiter used for the containing attribute, use XML entity references. (These are no use for escaping the string delimiter because they are expanded before the XPath parser gets to see them).

There's no way to escape the string delimiter in XSLT 1.0. The best way is to use a variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="x">name of' class</xsl:variable>
<xsl:apply-templates select="Object[@class=$x]"/>
```

Comment: By the way, PLEASE tell us which version of XSLT you are using. It's very frustrating to have to give two answers to a question when you're only interested in one of them.

Comment: i am using XslCompiledTransform processor and xslt 1.0 . when i used your solution it is fine in select attribute but in mode it is showing error in vs. like this    <xsl:apply-templates select="Object[@class=$x]" mode="$x" /> and error is -: mode attribute is invalid and $x is invalid according to data type ...

Comment: @NileshKhaire, the mode attribute does not allow XPath expressions, it needs to follow the rules for a qualified XML name so e.g. `mode="m1"` or `mode="ns1:m2"` (where you then need to declare a namespace for the prefix `ns1`).

Comment: @MartinHonnen Yes but in my case i want same class name and mode name . How can i add Apostrophe in mode then ?

Comment: The XML specification and the XML namespaces specification define the characters allowed in a qualified name. An apostrophe is not allowed in such a name.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `<xsl:apply-templates select="Object[@class=&quot;name of' class&quot;]"`. That way you compare the `class` attribute value to the string literal `name of' class`. With XSLT/XPath 2.0 you could also write `<xsl:apply-templates select="Object[@class='name of'' class']"` I think.

Comment: I am using Visual studio but after adding your solution still it is showing error .

Comment: Which error message do you get? And make sure you don't try my second suggestion with Visual Studio as that does not support XSLT/XPath 2.0.

Comment: Please edit your stylesheet and post a minimal but complete sample allowing us to reproduce the problem. I don't see why `select="Object[@class=&quot;name of' class&quot;]"` or `select='Object[@class="name of&#39; class"]'` should pose any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select='Object[@class="name of&#39; class"]'
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have a better idea. The above works with libxslt, Xalan and Saxon.